# A second order differential Equation isn't being solved by the application of $2$ Boundary Conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> $y''+25y=0\qquad\qquad y'(0)=6\qquad\qquad y'(\pi)=-9$

What class of Problem is this?

Is it solvable?

Comment: This is a boundary value problem (BVP). Every solution to it is periodic with period $2\pi/5$ **and** odd around the half-period - see DonAntonio's comment below - & thus the same is true of the derivative of each solution. Since $\pi$ corresponds to $2.5$ periods, $y'(\pi)=-y'(0)$ for *all* solutions - busted; the BVs cannot be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

$$y''+25y=0\implies y''=-25 y\implies y=A\cos5t+B\sin5t\implies$$

$$\begin{cases}6&=y'(0)&=5B\cos 0&=5B\\{}\\-9&=y'(\pi)&=5B\cos5\pi&=-5B\end{cases}$$

So it doesn't seem solvable....